# Managing the GCM Registration ID's

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Every App has its own Registration ID when using GCM. Is that true right 
or does every **User** has its own Registration ID? I need to know that because
if it is one Registration ID for each Application i need to implement something 
to handle the scenario that a user uses the device of another user to login 
to the application. I store all Registration ID's in the database one for 
each user. So if i for example have:

- Device A of User A
- Device B of User B

And User B is now logging in using Device A i have to update the Registration ID
in my Database for User B and it will set to the Registration ID of the App on 
Device A. So User A and B will temporally have the sam Registration ID until
User B logs in on Device B again and i update my Database.

I hope you understood what i mean and can tell me if this is how i need to 
do it to make sure that every user gets his/her push notifications even when
he is logged in on another device.

Would it be also a good idea to delete the registration id from the database
when the user is logging out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registration ID is intended to provide a connection between an instance of your application on a device and your servers so that you can route messages to an appropriate device. You will probably want to separately maintain an association between devices and users so that, given a message to a user, you can route that message to all the devices belonging to that user; however, conceptually, you should think of the registration ID as identifying your application (not a specific user) on a specific device.

Comment: so implementing a list of registration id's for each user would be a better idea. push notifications can than be send to all devices an i just have to check on which device the user is logged in. thank you

Comment: That's quite literally the opposite of what I said. Multiple users can exist on a single device at a time, but you really want to route messages to all the users on the device using a single registration ID for the device. Tying the registration ID to the user will also result in unnecessary network communication when toggling current users, and avoiding that is one of the reasons to use GCM in the first place.

Comment: But then i really dont understand how i can send push notifications to a user... i have to store the registration id somewhere and i also have to bind the user to it because otherwise i would never be able to send push notifications to the correct device of the correct user.

Comment: Right, I'm saying that you need to store these separately. When you get the registration ID, then you should send the registration ID as well as the list of users to your server in order to save the registration ID as well as to maintain a mapping from user ID to a list of registration IDs. Doing this is also helpful if, for example, you have updates for multiple users on a device... you can send them to your app with the same push notification.

Comment: ok i am now completely confused because that is again what i wrote in my first comment and in my post. one user downloads my app and registers. so i now have on user, one device and one registration id. now another users logs in into the same app on the same device. now i have two users, one device and on registration id. but the second user now downloads my app by himself on his device. now the user has too registration ids. on on from the device of the first user and on from his own device. So every user should have a list of registration ids and every registration id can have more users m:n

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your initial post, then. It sounded like you were going to unregister/reregister with GCM every time the user changed on a device. I didn't realize you were simply talking about your own mapping of user to registration ID.